# How to construct a loop in ATS?

Tags: ats

For instance, how can I write something in ATS corresponding to the following code in C:

```
void myloop(int n)
{
   int i;
   for (i = 0; i < n; i += 1) printf("i = %i\n", i);
   return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One can replicate this in a way that's remarkably close to the C version:

```
fun myloop (n: int): void = let
    var i: int
in
    for (i := 0; i < n; i := i + 1) begin
        println! ("i = ", i)
    end
end
```

A minor caveat: As far as I know, there is no format string support in `print` and `println`.

Comment: This direct approach becomes quite burdensome if linear types are involved (or really, anything beyond the simple examples...), and the programmer will need lots of annotations for it to work. Personally, this approach is my favorite, but it seems that Hongwei doesn't like it.

Answer (score 1):

If you like combinators, try this one

```
//
staload "share/atspre_staload.hats"
staload "share/HATS/atspre_staload_libats_ML.hats"
//
fun myloop(n: int): void =
  (n).foreach()(lam i => $extfcall(void, "printf", "i = %i\n", i))
//
```

When compiling the code, you need the flag -DATS_MEMALLOC_LIBC. You can try the code here:

https://glot.io/snippets/ejjr3j1pil

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to do this in functional programming is to implement a tail-recursive function:

```
fun myloop
  (n: int): void = let
  fun myloop2
    (n: int, i: int): void =
    if i < n then (println! ("i = ", i); myloop2(n, i+1)) else ()
  // end of [myloop2]
in
  myloop2(n, 0)
end // end of [myloop]
```